# How do I create a method for a table view in Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I made a table view in Sequel, and put it in a file `db_views.rb`:

```
require 'db_manip'    
Db_manip::DB.create_view(:bn_view,'SELECT ...')
```

To follow the "fat model thin controller" practice, I want to create some methods for `:bn_view`.

Comment: Assuming you had a model, I'm guessing you'd want to use dataset_module to add methods to the model's dataset.  For plain datasets, just extend them with a module containing those methods. But you need to be more specific about what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
class BnView < Sequel::Model(:bn_view)
  def foo
    # implement your method here
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer what I need is actually a class method. So I use def self.foo